# how to add menu items to action bar in more than 30 activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, menu, menuitem

I have created an app in android studio that has more than 30 activities .I created menu items in some activities by adding them in individual menu files and they worked fine .

But the problem is that it is a real headache to add all the menu items in menu files of each activity.So how to solve this issue ? can i use a custom menu file for all activities ? if yes, than how ?

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: create Activity which will add menu item, and then those 30 activities extends it.

Comment: yes the concept of base activity can be used which will have the menu items which are common for all the activities and then let all your other activities extend this one. You can handle the click events, or visibility of items as per your requirement in the base activity itself.

Comment: Please give any other way to solve this ,I don't want all my activities to be sub class of one activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option A**

A base `Activity` class that implements the logic for the menu items - in this case all 30 of your Activities should extend the base Activity.

This approach has the serious limitation that it forces you to extend a class even though you may need to extend another since Java does not support multiple inheritance. That's the reason for the common mantra "favor composition over inheritance".

**Option B**

Create a `Fragment` that calls `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in its `onCreate` callback and add an instance of this fragment to all your activities in their own `onCreate` callbacks. The fragment does not need to override `onCreateView`, since it doesn't inflate any layout.

This approach has a bit of added complexity, but the payoff is that you are not forced to inherit from a base class for all your activities.

Comment: Yes you are right I don't want all my activities to be restricted for one parent class but please explain your answer easier way . I didn't understood that ,I am new in programing